# Gaussian width of intersection of cube and ball in high-dimensional euclidean space

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, measure-concentration, geometric-probability

Let $d$ be a large positive integer and fix $r \ge 0$. Set $S := B_2^n \cap [-r,r]^d$, where $B_2^d$ is the euclidean unit-ball in $\mathbb R^d$. Finally, let $\omega(S)$ be the *Gaussian width* of $S$, defined by

$$
\omega(S) := \mathbb E \sup_{x \in S} x^\top z,
$$

where the expectation is over $z \sim N(0,I_d)$.

> **Question.** What is a good upper-bound for $\omega(T)$, valid for large $d$ ?

**Note.** Using [Proposition 1 of this manuscript](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.10696.pdf) with $T = [-1/\sqrt{d},1/\sqrt{d}]^d$ (the convex hull of $m=2^d$ points in $B_2^d$), and $s=1/(r\sqrt{d})$, I'm able to obtain the following upper-bound
$$
\omega(S)  = s\cdot\omega(s B_2^d \cap T) \lesssim r\sqrt{d\log(em)} \land \sqrt{d} = rd \land \sqrt{d}.
$$

Unfortunately, the above bound is not very good for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, up to a constant factor $\omega(S) = \Theta(\min(\sqrt{d}, rd))$.

To see the upper bound, we can use the fact that if $S \subset Q$, then $\omega(S) \leq \omega(Q)$, therefore
$$
\omega(B_2^n \cap r B_\infty^n) \leq \min(\omega(B_2^n), r \omega(B_\infty^n)) = \min( \mathbb{E}_{z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)} \|z\|_2, r\, \mathbb{E}_{z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)} \|z\|_1) = \mathcal{O}(\min(\sqrt{d}, rd)).
$$

For the lower bound, note that for any given vector $z$, we can chose $\tilde{z} \in S$ to be $\tilde{z}_i := \min(1/\sqrt{d}, r) \mathrm{sgn}(z_i)$. With this choice, we have  for any fixed $z$
$$\sup_{x \in S} x^T z \geq \tilde{z}^T z = \min(1/\sqrt{d}, r) \sum_i |z_i| = \min(1/\sqrt{d}, r) \|z\|_1,$$
and therefore $\omega(S) \geq \min(1/\sqrt{d}, r) \mathbb{E}_{z\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)} \|z\|_1 = \Omega(\min(\sqrt{d}, rd)$.

Note that this is not inconsistent with the upper bound given by Proposition 1 in the cited paper --- the hypercube $[-r, r]^d$ has $2^d$ vertices, not $2d$.

Comment: Thanks. I see where my error came from. My $T=[-1/\sqrt{d},1/\sqrt{d}]^d$ is not the convex hull of $m=2d$ but $m=2^d$, points in $B_2^d$. Then, $\log(em) \asymp d$ and not $\sqrt{d}$ as I carelessly thought.